# Uncaught Reference Error: function is not defined at onLoad (firebase.js)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, import, onload

I get this error when trying to load a function from javascript module at bottom of html page.

dex.html:101 Uncaught ReferenceError: findData is not defined
at onload (index.html:101:80)

New to html and .js in general, trying to make a html/js page with a guest list:

html with text inputs at top, javascript module at bottom of body with onclick eventlisteners and functions to send text stored as var to firebase database

have a function findData which gets the firebase data and updates the h3 html tags of id Name, Phone, and Insta with the corresponding keys from that child:

function findData() {
var database = firebase.database().ref();

```
                 var peopleRef = database.child('People');
         
                 People.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
                        snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
                               findName.innerHTML += "Name: " + snapshot.val().Name;
                               findPhone.innerHTML += "Phone: " + snapshot.val().Phone;
                               findInsta.innerHTML += "Insta: " + snapshot.val().Insta + "<br>";
                               console.log(snapshot.val());
                               
                        })
                 })
          }
```

I want the list updated instantly when you refresh, I know there's probably many ways you could go with having the data updated in html, for me, i thought onLoad seemed most straightforward:

causes this error:

dex.html:101 Uncaught ReferenceError: findData is not defined
at onload (index.html:101:80)

:(

I'm using the cdn src links in the module script opening tag, and importing from those links below inside the module.

I tried using window.findData = findData; inside the module, and calling findData(); in a separate  in the html at the top, didnt seem to work (if the syntax was even correct). Maybe this is too much for a noob like me, but I feel like I am so close and just need to be able to call findData() on page load.

How can I fix this issue and have findData load correctly on page refresh?

Comment: While the snippet shows how you define the `findData` function, it doesn't show where the problem is in the `onload` callback. Can you please add your whole `<script>` tags to your question, in the same order they appear in your file, making sure to omit any sensitive info using `// ...` to show removed code.